# Integrating Filament Dashboard in a blade file

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-filament, filamentphp

I have created my admin dashboard in filament, yet I want to integrate the dashboard into a blade file. is this possible ? I need all the functionalities of the dashboard except the side bar. how to do so ? is it applicable ?

resarching but i could not find anything on the web